# Creating a Simple IsNullOrFalse method for both a method and its caller

Tags: c#

I find myself doing this a lot.

```
if( obj == null || !obj.SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean() ) {
  // then do this
}
```

I mean, I just see it cluttering up code in a lot of places. It isn't really a bad thing, but what's the fun of syntactical sugar if you can't sprinkle it around here and there where it makes things slimmer?

So I tried to just make a very humble little method, `IsNullOrFalse`. The idea is that it will test for what was passed in, see if it is null, and if not, it will run the method, and return the boolean result.

This has actually proven a lot harder than I imagined. I don't really need this to continue on in any project, but at this point I have gone from curious to intrigued.

Has anyone else done something like this? The problem I am getting is that I cannot pass in something that does not exist that contains a method.

Comment: Doesn't look like clutter to me. But I wonder, what causes `obj` to potentially come in as null?

Comment: Be careful not to make something that's too clever just for the sake of being clever.

Comment: `obj` would come in as null if it ...well, was null. Clutter isn't the appropriate word, I just wanted to see if I could do it. I do not think it has any practical application at this point. It just became a new aspect of C# I had never explored when I discovered the delegate relationship involved, and I want to see if anyone else has tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more generic version of @JaredPar's answer:

```
    public static TResult ValueOrDefaultIfNull<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> getter, TResult defaultValue = default(TResult)) where T : class
    {
        return obj != null ? getter(obj) : defaultValue;
    }
```

And usage:

```
        if (!obj.ValueOrDefaultIfNull(mc => mc.SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean()))
        {

        }
```

This can return return any type, not just bool, so for instance you can do something like:

```
string zipCode = contact
    .ValueOrDefaultIfNull(c=>c.Address)
    .ValueOrDefaultIfNull(a=>a.ZipCode, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extension method which will do the trick

```
public static bool IsNullOrFalse<T>(this T value, Func<T, bool> del) 
  where T : class { 
  return value == null || !del(value);
}
```

Now you can write

```
if (obj.IsNullOrFalse(o => o.SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean())) {
  ...
}
```

Note: I personally wouldn't take this approach and would prefer the long hand.  This solution incurs extra allocations (closure + delegate) and generally speaking isn't much shorter than the original.

Also I cringe ever time I see an extension method which operates on `null` values.  While completely legal in C# it does make the call site code difficult to follow for developers not aware the API is an extension method.

Comment: ehm, actually that isn't an extension method! :P

Comment: @AS-CII doh! Left off the `this`.  Added

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wanted to you could use a method that checks for `null` and executes a predicate if not null:

```
public bool IsNullOrFalse(object obj, Func<bool> predicate)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return true;

    else return !predicate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution of your problem. You can create a standard Empty instance of an object (like String.Empty, DateTime.MinValue, etc.), which will return false when your SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean() is called.
Then your caller code will look like this:

```
if ((obj ?? objEmpty).SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean()){ 
    // then do this
}
```

The ?? operator will use objEmpty instance when obj is null and `objEmpty.SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean()` will return false when it is called for objEmpty.

However this may take some efforts inside your SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean() methods:

```
private bool isEmptyInstance;    
public bool SomeMethodThatReturnsABoolean()
{
  if (isEmptyInstance) { return false; }

  // rest of the method
}
```